# Dialogflow doesn't show response from webhook

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I have a webhook for my Dialogflow agent that grabs jokes from Reddit to show to the user if they ask "Tell a joke". I have my webhook hosted on Heroku, and whenever I ask the question, Heroku's console shows that the joke gets requested, but my agent doesn't show this at all.

Here is a snippit of my webhook:

```js
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/webhook', function (request, res) {
    
    if (request.body.queryResult.parameters['reddit']) {
            var reddit = request.body.queryResult.parameters['reddit'];
            callRedditInfo(reddit)
                .then((output) => {
                let queryResult = toApiAiResponseMessage(output.value, output.value, toTelgramObject(output.value, 'Markdown'));    
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output    }));
            })
            .catch(errorHandler)
    }

});

function getSubreddit (reddit) {
 if (reddit == "funny" || reddit == "joke" || reddit == "laugh")
   return {sub: "jokes", displayText: "joke"};
   else {
     return {sub: "todayILearned", displayText: "fact"};
   }
}

function callRedditInfo(reddit) {
 let subReddit = getSubreddit(reddit);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log('API request: to Reddit');
   https.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subReddit["sub"]}/top.json?sort=top&t=day`, (res) => {
        let body = '';    
        res.on('data', (d) => body += d);
        res.on('end', () => {
            let response = JSON.parse(body);
            let thread = response["data"]["children"][(Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1))]["data"];
            let output = `Here's a ${subReddit["displayText"]}: ${thread["title"]}`;
       
            if (subReddit['sub'] == "jokes") {
            output /*+= " " */+ thread["selftext"];
            }

            output //+="\nWhat do you want to hear next, a joke or a fact?"
            console.log(output);
            resolve(output);
            });
     
             res.on('error', (error) => {
             reject(error);   
            });
        });
    });
}

function toTelgramObject(text, parse_mode) {
    return {
        text: text,
        parse_mode: parse_mode
    }
}

function toApiAiResponseMessage(speech, displayText, telegramObject = null) {
    return {
        speech: speech,
        displayText: displayText,
        data: {
            telegram: telegramObject
        }
    }
}

function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(toApiAiResponseMessage(error, error, toTelgramObject(error, 'Markdown'))));
}

app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000), function () {
    console.log("Server listening");
});
```

Here is a snippet of my Heroku console after I typed "Tell a joke" in my Dialogflow agent's dashboard:

```
app[web.1]: API request: to Reddit
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=arya-webhooks.herokuapp.com request_id=c07a63f8-1cb3-4a3d-8fb1-2fe2fc606622 fwd="66.249.83.65" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=615ms status=200 bytes=334 protocol=https
app[web.1]: Here's a joke: A Duck is about to cross the road
```

I basically followed [THIS guide](https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/making-a-reddit-chatbot-using-dialogflow) to setup my Dialogflow agent.

[Screenshot of my intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkGtJ.png) and
[Screenshot of my entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJu86.png)